# Wifi Hight LAtency and Packet Loss - But No interference

Tags: wifi, latency

I am using Wifi points (SSID name: "ve-E" and "ve-E1")(both 2.4Ghz) 
After a through scan, in order to avoid Interference, I assigned a different channels to them (6, 7).
But occasionally I observe a high latency and packet loss. 
Below Figures Shows the latency (varying between 4 to 5000 ms !!)

-- Can some one help me, any advanced techniques to find out where its going wrong , so that I can reduce the packet loss. --

[image]

At the same instance i checked if there was any interference, the scanner(below image) shows there is no interference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jut saw this article 
"Bear in mind that tools like inSSIDer that plot which SSIDs cover which channels/frequencies at which power levels are designed to LOOK like RF spectrum analyzers, but they are not true RF spectrum analyzers. They take normal Wi-Fi network scan results lists and plot them. They are not capable of detecting or plotting non-Wi-Fi energy, so they'll never show the interference from microwave ovens, cordless phones, baby monitors, or any other non-Wi-Fi device that uses the 2.4GHz or 5GHz bands.
"
Ref:: https://superuser.com/questions/973209/wi-fi-interference-and-loss-of-ssids-in-scans.

Looks like  my scanner might miss to scan the routers which have isolated its ssid , the nearby microwave, any hidden Bluetooth devices etc ...